# RabbitMQ EventingBasicConsumer concurrency consideration

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, rabbitmq

I was reading through the [.NET API Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) and it is pretty good information but I'm a bit confused on how RabbitMQ manages threads. Under the **Concurrency Consideration** section it states that every IConnection is backed up by a single background thread. Then it continues with:

> The one place where the nature of the threading model is visible to the application is in any callback the application registers with the library. Such callbacks include:
>
> - any IBasicConsumer method
> - the BasicReturn event on IModel
> - any of the various shutdown events on IConnection, IModel etc.

I'm a bit confused by this. Do they mean that every time `HandleBasicDeliver` is called a new thread is created? In that case there will be as many threads as messages are received and the concurrency is controlled by the prefetch count along with the number of consumers?

So if we consider a case where I have **one** `IConnection` and **two** channels (`IModel`) with prefetch count of **one** and **one** `EventingBasicConsumer` per channel, how many threads would we have running in the application?

Answer (score 2):

I have done considerable amount of research on this topic since I first asked the question so I thought I would post it here in case someone finds this information useful.

- Take this with a grain of salt.  These are my understandings of how rabbit (C#) works.

  1. IConnection is an actual socket connection. It will have a single thread polling it. According to suggestions I have read, use one connection per application unless you have a reason to use more.

     - Using more than one connection does not necessarily mean that you have better fault tolerance since if a connection fails, there usually is a problem that will result in all the connections to fail.  Also, in many cases using one connection is enough to handle the traffic coming from the network and it is simply unnecessary to have more. 
       http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-July/013771.html
       http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-May/019873.html
  2. In C# channels are not considered thread safe so it is not a bad idea to have a channel per thread, otherwise one should make sure to use locking mechanism.
     https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html
  3. As per my understanding of reading the source code, handleBasicDeliver (and I think all IModel calls) is ran in a Task.  With that in mind, having multiple consumers does increase the concurrency of your software since if one consumer receives a message and is busy processing it, another consumer is free to pick up a message and execute it in a different thread. Also, each consumer must be on its own channel to maximize concurrency otherwise message order is preserved. However, if that kind of concurrency is not welcome consider using a single channel to ensure the messages are processed in the order they arrived.
     NOTE: Point 3 may have changed in that channel order is no longer preserved. I haven't had time to explore the new changes so read through this and draw your own conclusion:
     https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/251

Answer (score 0):

I have revised my answer and research that you did looks good.

I have created an application using Rabbitmq and in that I had a situation where I have to share the same IConnection(Connection) for number of IModel(channel). And that is the way we should use one connection as one connection is enough for serving multiple channels.

The problem I faced once was if I am creating one connection per client then the number of connections for that queue goes on increasing which results in termination of the application after a while.

So we should avoid having multiple connections unless its needed. If possible only one connection should be used for multiple channels.

### Various shut down events on IConnection, IModel:

The IModel even if goes down the IConnection is still there. But if the IConnection is down then all the IModel under that connection will be shut down.

Comment: that is an interesting suggestion. Did you perhaps mean to say we should have multiple channels per connection? The Pivotal people suggest having as little connections as possible and then creating channels (virtual connections in a way) as you need them.